# Optimal way to create implicit view for Java objects in Scala

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion

I am working with a Java library. This library has a bunch of collections for which I want to have implicit views in my Scala code. The Java library's object model follows a pattern like this:

> (NarrowStreet | WideStreet) *extends* Street *extends* Road *extends* TwoNode
>
> StreetList *extends* java.util.AbstractList< Street>
>
> RoadList *extends* java.util.AbstractList< Road>

and so on. A `StreetList` virtually behaves like a `List<Street>`.

I need to use a method in this library which has the following signature:

```
List<StreetList> city.getStreets();
```

In Scala, I do the following to implicitly get to a `Seq[Street]` collection:

```
implicit def twoNodeView[T <: java.util.AbstractList[_ <: TwoNode]](x : T): Seq[_ <: TwoNode] = for(i <- 0 until x.size()) yield x.get(i)
```

Now when I do

```
city.getStreets.asScala.flatten //.map, .filter, etc.
```

it gives me a `Seq[TwoNode]`. I cast the objects when I use the collection in a `map` or `filter` function and I think I am safe since I am 100% sure that this object is a `Seq[Street]` and not really a `Seq[TwoNode]`.

Questions:

1. Are there any fail scenarios the way I am implementing the implicit view?
2. Can this be improved or is there a better way to achieve the same result and avoid casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define your own implicits for this. Just use

```
city.getStreets.asScala.map(_.asScala)
```

to get the nested `Buffer[Buffer[Street]]` and then `.flatten` it into `Seq[Street]` if you want.